# How to modify term reference

Tags: 7, hooks

I have added term reference field on one content type i want to alter that term reference list. I have search in drupal.org site but not information is find. Can any one help me how to alter the termreference list.

Present terms display like this : term1,term2

but i want to add another field data also like ex: term1(count-2), term2(count-3)

Term reference:

[image]

Comment: You may need to explain what (count-x) is

Comment: I want to display node count associated that term

Comment: Have you tried https://www.drupal.org/project/views? Or do you prefer php coding in template?

Comment: This count should display on node edit page.